# Zend_Translate : Auto-extract string from views

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, zend-translate

i don't figure out a way to extract automaticaly string to be translated in files.

For instance, you've got in your layout and views some `echo $this->translate('my_string');` and I want to created the files 'en_US.php', 'fr_FR.php', 'es_ES.php' with the comparative array :

```
<?php return array('my_string' => 'translation of my string'); ?>
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: i think you need the gettext adapater and an tool like poedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Zend_Translate adapters and choose one. I warmly recommend the gettext adapter.

Here is how to implement i18n in your Zend Framework application:

1. Setup a translation adapter during Bootstrap
2. Store the adapter object in the registry with Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
3. Wrap all text in the equivalent of $translate->translate('This is translatable text');
4. Install 'gettext' on your development machine.
5. Install and setup poEdit. poEdit will scan your application and find all translatable strings. It will then store them in a .po file, which you can edit and multiply for other languages.
6. When you're done, save it and poEdit stores creates the .mo files. The Zend_Translate gettext adapter needs those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

Put in your `application.ini`:

```
resources.translate.adapter = Array
resources.translate.locale = fr_FR
resources.translate.disableNotices = true
resources.translate.data = APPLICATION_PATH "/data"
```

And put file `fr_FR.php` in your `APPLICATION_PATH "/data"` directory. It should work.

The file must be something like this:

```
return array (
   'Good day' => 'Bojour',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP to translate a project is handy for small project, and consequently you shouldn't need such tools.

There are such tools for [gettext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html#zend.translate.adapter.gettext), like [poedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poedit/), which will parse your project and search for the given function/method (`translate()`). POedit will generate .po file which basicly consists of plain/text file which looks like:

```
#: src/name.c:36
msgid "My name is %s.\n"
msgstr ""
```

If you really need to use a PHP file for your translation, you may try some `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, something like this should give a starting point (**not tested**):

```
echo "return array(" > mytranslation.php | \
grep "translate(" * | \
cut -f1 | \
sed -r 's@.*translate\((.*)\).*@\1 => "Not translated yet",@' >> mytranslation.php && \
echo ");" >> mytranslation.php
```